# How can I download the installer for macOS Sierra 10.12?

Tags: macos, upgrade

I have a MacBook Pro running El Capitan that I need to upgrade to Sierra 10.12 (not High Sierra) for development reasons.

I have previously upgraded my personal computer as follows: El Capitan -> Sierra -> High Sierra.  Knowing that, I should be able to see the previous version in the App Store as outlined in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/208801/68852).

However, I don't see Sierra in my Purchased tab in the App Store:

[image: App Store]

Was Sierra 10.12 completely removed from the store (including previous purchases)?

Comment: There is now an official page with the Sierra downloader - see the edited answer below (or the edit history for the time window when this wasn't possible)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple now has a page up and live store links to download Sierra after High Sierra was announced. These links will change annually for the expected future, so please consider using Apple articles [or other answers here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309400/5472) to locate the correct links if the ones below change or are removed.

- startup keys help recovery select multiple versions https://support.apple.com/HT204904
- official support article on old download options https://support.apple.com/HT211683

---

Apple makes Sierra available even after High Sierra is released. Use the safari browser for all these links, please is you run into issues

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208202

The link to the installer on the Mac App Store is: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-sierra/id1127487414?ls=1&mt=12

If for some reason that article or link are gone, you may need to have an Apple ID that [previously downloaded 10.12 Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300257/how-can-i-get-the-original-sierra-installer-now-that-high-sierra-is-out) - then it will be in purchased and a quick download. If you feel it’s missing, check with Apple Store support and your “purchase” receipt emails / purchase history. This is a change from [older releases where you had to make sure and get an installer purchased before general release](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254720/download-el-capitan-installer-now-that-sierra-is-out).

[If Sierra legitimately isn’t in your purchased list,](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286311/macos-sierra-doesnt-appear-in-my-purchased-list-within-the-mac-app-store) and for some reason the KB above gets pulled at some point:

- You might be able to take your Mac to Apple Service and have the OS loaded.
- You might be able to use [Internet Recovery to install the OS that came with your Mac - so you’d need to buy or have a Mac that shipped with 10.12.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)
- Find someone you trust to make you a [bootable Install macOS Sierra installer](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) drive - a 8 GB USB drive works well for this.

Comment: Direct .dmg http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2019/cert/061-39476-20191023-48f365f4-0015-4c41-9f44-39d3d2aca067/InstallOS.dmg

Comment: If the *Sierra installer link* isn't working, try using **Safari**.

Comment: Well said @LordElrond I’ve edited this to point at better guidance as well that’s more updated than most of this answer.

Answer (score -2):

you may use this link to download Sierra
https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/macos-sierra/id1127487414?mt=12

Comment: How does this differ from the link in the existing answer?

Comment: @patrix It's a tiny bit different. The existing/above link is no longer working for me.

Comment: The link in my answer and posted to this comment is still the active one Apple publishes. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-sierra/id1127487414?ls=1&mt=12 It works in multiple geographic locations for us.  Are you able to use https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208202 to get a working link @LangLangC

Comment: @langlangc both links work for me. If a link in an answer is broken, usually an edit is better than a link-only answer

Comment: @bmike the link with `ls=1` in it just opened the AppStore.app on its default page, while the one in this answer opened the correct page. But it seems to have been a temp glitch. Now both arrive at the correct page… Weird. (at)Patrix: I can agree to all of that.